# Disable Jquery Spinner (sets value 0)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, spinner

I have a problem to disable my jquery spinners. They look like this:

```
<input id='A1' style='width:45px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block' min='0' max='999'>
<input id='A2' style='width:45px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block' min='0' max='999'>
<input id='A3' style='width:45px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block' min='0' max='999'>
<input id='A4' style='width:45px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block' min='0' max='999'>
...
```

...

They work fine, but when I want to disabled them, their value becomes 0 OR it gives me errors.
This I've tried (one by one, not all at once):

```
$("#content :input").prop("disabled", true); //disable all other inputs, commenting this does not change, just added it here to show all
$('input[id^="A"]').spinner({disabled:true}); //sets value to 0
$("[id^=A]").spinner("disable"); 
$("[id^=A]").spinner( "option", "disabled", true);
$('input[id^="A"]').spinner( "option", "disabled", true); // gives warning method does not exist
```

It's the JQuery default spinner, nothing special.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code snippets are for runnable demos... Your HTML or JS alone isn't runnable. Please either link the external libraries, and HTML required HTML,CSS & JS to create a demo or remove the snippet and make it a code block.

Comment: I just thought it was a new feature of StackOverflow :P

Comment: What do you mean by `spinner`? Is it this http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ ?

Comment: @DieterDeKeyser of course it is a new cool feature of SO, but you've to use it properly otherwise it's useless and will throw errors in our console...

Comment: @watou: yes, and I checked the example and the API, but it's not helping me.
TJ: it was not on purpose ;-)

Comment: I put together a fiddle of your page and it seems to work fine if you use the spinner('disable') method. Maybe there is something else on your page that is causing a problem? http://jsfiddle.net/s73ds5e7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
jQuery.each($("[id^=A]"), function (i, spinObj) {
                            spinObj.spinner("disable");
                        });
```

becouse of `$("[id^=A]")` and all of your selectors returns array of objects